# Set columns and data from parent to child with Table Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I need to get from the parent component the ability to define the columns and data of the object to be displayed in a child component, which is a bootstrap table.
I have no problem going through a normal Input() decorator and defining the columns and data to be displayed. The problem comes when I want to show the data of an object inside the object.
This is my example JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  }
},
```

I define my columns and data to show as follows in the parent component:

```
  colData = [
  { id: "name", header: "Name" },
  { id: "username", header: "User Name" },
  { id: "email", header: "Email" },
  { id: "address.city", header: "City?" } // here is not rendering the property
];
```

My Child component HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: auto;" 
            scope="col" 
            *ngFor="let key of ColData; let i = index"> 
            <span>
                {{key.header}} 
            </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of GridData; index as i" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td *ngFor="let key of ColData">
            <span>  
                {{ item[key.id] }}  
            </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where GridData is the JSON above. In the TBody I am looping the property like "item.(name, email, etc..)" and with those works, but does not render the property "item.address.city". Why is that? or is there some other way to achieve this?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4hpcep) for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :
add a child filed to the colData

```
colData = [
    { id: "name", header: "Name" },
    { id: "username", header: "User Name" },
    { id: "email", header: "Email" },
    { id: "address", header: "City?", field: "city" } // here
  ];
```

and then do this in HTML

```
<td *ngFor="let key of ColData">
                <span *ngIf="key.field">
                {{ record[key.id][key.field] }}  
            </span>
                <span *ngIf="!key.field">{{ record[key.id]}}</span>
</td>
```

working blitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j6mxvs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbootstrap-table%2Fbootstrap-table.component.html

Comment: I tried that way but without the ngif and that's why it didn't work, rookie mistake. This answer is what worked for me, I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

if you want "extends" the idea, you can use two functions:

```
  getData(colName:string,data:any)
  {
    if (colName.indexOf('.')<0)
      return data[colName]
    const part=colName.split('.')
    const field=part.shift()
    return this.getData(part.join("."),data[field])
  }
```

And

```
  private calculateNewData(){
    this.data.forEach(item=>{
      this.colData.forEach(col=>{
        if (col.id.indexOf('.')){
          item[col.id.replace('.','_')]=this.getData(col.id,item)
        }
      })
    })
    this.colData.forEach(col=>{
      if (col.id.indexOf('.')>0)
         col.id=col.id.replace('.','_')
    })

  }
```

In a getter you check if you has data and dataColumns

```
  data:any;
  colData:any;

  @Input() set GridData(value){
    this.data=value
    if (this.colData){
        this.calculateNewData()

    }
  }
  @Input() set ColData(value)
  {
    this.colData=value;
    if (this.data)
       this.calculateNewData()
  }
```

And iterate over colData and data, see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdc4lj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbootstrap-table%2Fbootstrap-table.component.ts)

Comment: Eliseo, I appreciate every answer from you, you already helped me with other problems. You gave me a few more ideas to implement with this comment, I appreciate it enormously of a newcomer in angular.